# How do I update live time using custom time from API rather than Date() in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, timer, nstimer

I have a problem showing live time on my `UILabel`.

It's working fine if I use `Date()`:

```swift
var timer = Timer()

// I use this in viewDidLoad:
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(tick),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

// and tick func is:

@objc func tick() {
    print("tick")

    let time1 = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(),
                                              dateStyle: .none,
                                              timeStyle: .medium)

    serverTime.text = time1    
}
```

It can update my label every time.

But I don't want to use `Date()`. I want to use something like "2018-12-10 17:29:50" from my API.

But when I use that, the label does not update every time.
And what should i use ? Date() or calender.current ? . Give me an example please :)

Comment: To do this you need to constantly request new data from the API (once per second) _and_ the API needs to publish new data constantly. Does the API support this and can your app handle so many requests?

Comment: I think it will be bad idea if hit data per 1 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. request your api get the time
2. convert it to a Date by DateFormatter
3. convert the date to a timestamp
4. create a timer. update label by the timestamp++

```
var timestamp = 0

{
   YourAPI.request() {
        let dateString = aDateFromYourServer
        let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
        timestamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970
        createTimer()
   }
}

@objc func timerSelector() {
    timestamp = timestamp + 1
    let newDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
    label.text = ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer . where i should put this ?

Comment: I have reedit the code.